# Can you upload a new ios app version from another xcode project?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I created an app and published it under the name of Medications V1.001 (example name)
I did the exact app with updates but in another xcode project (Project name: Drugs). I want to upload a new version (Medications V1.002) in itunesconnect. Is it possible to upload a build to the existing itunesconnect app from the new xcode project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Bundle Identifer of your Xcode project matches the Bundle Identifier of your App (Medications V1.001) in iTunes Connect, you can upload your build and it will appear in the prerelease tab in iTunes Connect and you could use that build for an update (Medications V1.002). So change the Bundle Identifier in XCode to the one of your app in iTunes Connect.